# Analysis of the running time of concat

Tags: haskell, functional-programming, time-complexity

This is an example from Richard Bird's Thinking Functionally with Haskell (p. 158). Could someone explain me the reasoning behind 1,2,3 and 4?

EDIT.
I understand the first 3 equations formed from the first definition. For 1., why is a summation? How is it tie to T(++)(n, m) = Θ(n)?
For the second definition, I understand the first 2 statements. The third one (2.), why k+n?
For 3. and 4. I am completely lost

---

Consider first the following two definitions of concat:

```
concat xss= foldr (++) [] xss 
concat' xss = foldl (++) [] xss
```

The two definitions are equivalent provided xss is a finite list. Suppose xss is a list of length m of lists all of length n. Then the first definition gives

```
T(concat)(m, n) = T(foldr (++) [])(m, n),
T(foldr (++) [])(0, n) = Θ(1), 
T(foldr (++) [])(m+1, n) = T(++)(n, mn) + T(foldr (++) [])(m, n).
```

The estimate T(++)(n, mn) arises because a list of length n is concatenated with a list of length mn. Since T(++)(n, m) = Θ(n), we obtain

```
1. T(foldr (++) [])(m,n) = Σ_{k=0}^{m} Θ(n) = Θ(mn)
```

For the second definition of concat we have

```
T(concat')(m, n) = T(foldl (++))(0, m, n),  
T(foldl (++))(k, 0, n) = O(1), 
2. T(foldl (++))(k, m+1, n) = T(++)(k, n) + T(foldl (++))(k+n, m, n).
```

The additional argument k refers to the length of the accumulated list in the second argument of foldl. This time we obtain

```
3. T(foldl (++)) (k,m,n) = Σ_{j=0}{m-1} Θ(k+jn) = Θ(k+m^2n)
```

Hence

```
4. T(concat')(m, n) = Θ(m_2 n)
```

Comment: I think you should elaborate on what's unclear according to you. What you posted, in my eye, already explains the reasoning behind 1..4. If you want/need something more, it would help to provide more information. E.g. "I understand everything until X. The next steps claims Y -- why should Y hold?"

Comment: I edited my original post.

Comment: Less verbose notation might help. For #1, for example, f(m+1, n) = n + f(m, n). Equivalent: f(m) = n + f(m − 1) where n doesn’t change. Can you see how you rewrite f to be a summation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> For 1., why is a summation? How is it tie to `T(++)(n, m) = Θ(n)`?

The summation arises from the inductive definition. Consider this independent definition

```
g(0,n) = something
g(m+1,n) = f(m,n) + g(m,n)
```

By induction, we get

```
g(m,m)
= f(m-1,n) + g(m-1,n)
= f(m-1,n) + f(m-2,n) + g(m-2,n)
= f(m-1,n) + f(m-2,n) + f(m-3,n) + g(m-3,n)
= f(m-1,n) + f(m-2,n) + f(m-3,n) + ... + f(m-m,n) + g(m-m,n)
= f(m-1,n) + f(m-2,n) + f(m-3,n) + ... + f(m-m,n) + something
```

So, the result is a summation of `f(n,x)` where `x` varies, plus a final term `something`.

In the original definition, `g(m,n)` is `T(foldr (++) [])(m, n)`, while
`f(m,n) = T(++)(n, mn)`. The final term does not matter, asymptotically.

> For the second definition, I understand the first 2 statements.
>   The third one (2.), why k+n?

When computing `foldl (++) x ys`, `x` is assumed to be a list having length `k`, and `ys` to be a list-of-lists having length `m+1`, whose elements have length `n`.

Now, the recursive `foldl` equation is:

```
foldl (++) x (y:ys) = foldl (++) (x++y) ys
```

The cost of the recursive call comprises (A) the cost of `temp = x++y`, which is `T(++)(k, n)`, and (B) the cost of `foldl (++) temp ys`. For (B), the length of `temp` is now `length x + length y = k+n`, while `ys` has length `m` (`n` is unaffected).

So, we get

```
T(foldl (++))(k, m+1, n) 
= A           + B
= T(++)(k, n) + T(foldl (++))(k+n, m, n).
```

> For 3. and 4. I am completely lost

In 3. we sum, as we did for 1., the term `T(++)(k, n)` with `k` varying. Note that `k` increases by `n` every time we recurse, so we get

```
T(++)(k, n) + T(++)(k+n, n) + T(++)(k+n+n, n) + ...
= Σ_{j=0}{m-1} T(++)(k+jn, n)
= Σ_{j=0}{m-1} Θ(k+jn) 
= Θ(k+m^2 n)
```

In 4. we choose `k=0` since in the definition of `concat'` we initially pick `x=[]` whose length is `0`. So, only `Θ(m^2 n)` survives.